# Angular 1.1.5 url is duplicated when using ngInclude

Tags: angularjs, duplicates, hashbang, angularjs-ng-include

I'm using angular 1.1.5 with ngInclude in my template. Whenever I load the page I get a duplicate path after the hashbang: `http://localhost/home#/home`, `http://localhost/account#/account`, etc. This happens when there's `ngInclude` directive in the page (I think this also happens with `ngView`). I'm not using any routing with this app, and it's a very simple setup overall.

Using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` in the module configuration seems to resolve this, but I don't want to use that as it doesn't really fit with this application's design.

This doesn't seem to happen in angular 1.2.0-RC.2, but I don't want to migrate just yet. Any known workarounds? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function as the value:

```
app.controller("foo", function($scope) {

$scope.url = function() {
  return "/bar";
  }
});


<div ng-controller="foo">
  <ng-include src="url()"></ng-include>
</div>
```